# python2.7 sharepoint (0.4.1): can't iterate through rows of a large list (have an error in the source code)

Tags: python, sharepoint, soap

I'm trying to read data from a Share Point site by using python-sharepoint package (version 0.4.1). I can read data if it's small, but if there are more than 9,000 rows I have the error below:

*File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sharepoint\lists__init__.py", line 172, in rows
    for row in list(response[0][0][0]):
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1089, in lxml.etree._Element.**getitem** (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:47648)
IndexError: list index out of range*

My code is below (python2.7, windows 2007, RAM 8GB Memory (free ~ 4GB)):

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite
import urllib2
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

# my Windows credentials
username = "DOMAIN\\username"
password = "Password"

# the sharepoint info
server_url = "https://sharepoint_server.com/"
site_url = server_url + "sites/SharePointPlus"
list_name = 'List with more than 10,000 rows'
FieldName = 'Output Field' 

# an opener for the NTLM authentication
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, server_url, username, password)
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)
# create and install the opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# create a SharePointSite object
site = SharePointSite(site_url, opener)
sp_list = site.lists[list_name] 

for row in sp_list.rows:
    print row.id, row.FieldName
```

So it fails in the last 2 rows when I'm trying to iterate through rows in a big list. When a list is small, everything runs perfectly.

I looked at the source code sharepoint\lists__init__.py and it seems it fails on row 171:

```
response = self.opener.post_soap(LIST_WEBSERVICE, xml)
```

**xml** looks OK: *http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/}GetListItems at 0x3279b70>*)
but the **response** looks like this *http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Fault at 0x32805d0>*. 
While for small data the response looks like *http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/}GetListItemsResponse at 0x31355f8>*

I'm new to python and sharepoint and will appreciate any help and directions to dig in (not sure if it's code or hardware, probably my computer isn't powerful enough)

Thanks.